# How do you order the animation of a sprite one after the other in cocos2d?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone

I have two sprites. Both should animate. But sprite1 should animate first and after completion of the animation of sprite1, sprite2 animation should start. Can I say to a sprite to run from a certain time and end at a certain time ? This is my problems. Please explain how can I do that.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On of the easiest ways to do this is via CCActions, in particular having the CCCallFunc action call a method in your code to start up the sprite2 animation as soon as the sprite1 animation finishes. You then use CCSequence to create an action sequence of CCAnimate then CCCallFunc.

```
// Lets say you have this as the CCAnimation for Sprite1
CCAnimation *sprite1Animation = [CCAnimation …]…

// then you setup the animate action:
// Suppose you have a method called -(void)startSprite2Animation {} which starts the sprite2 animation :-)

id animateAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:sprite1Animation restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
id callSprite2Animation = [CCCallFunc ctionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startSprite2Animation)];
id animateAndActionSequence =  [CCSequence actions: animateAction, callSprite2Animation,nil];

[sprite1 stopAllActions]; // If you have actions running
[sprite1 runAction:animateAndActionSequence];

// See more on Cocos2D actions here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:actions
```

Comment: Thank you for that. At last I have got one answer for this. I will use in my program and If have any problems I would post to you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. It worked as I needed.
I think you are member from today. Have a good time here.
Thank you again.